# Java - Group paths list from first parent

Tags: java, path, parent-child, grouping

if i have a textual list of paths like this:

```
folder1/A
folder1/B/H
folder1/C/F
folder2/D
folder2/E
folder2/F
folder3/G
folder3/H
folder3/I
```

which is the best way to group them by the first directory?

An output like this:

```
folder1 [A, B/H, C/F]
folder2 [D, E, F]
folder3 [G, H, I]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a list of Strings `ls` as input containing all the Strings:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
for(String s: ls){
  String[] k = s.split("/");
  if(k.length<2)
     throw new RuntimeException("Invalid input");
  if(map.get(k[0]==null)
     map.put(k[0], new ArrayList<String>());
  map.get(k[0]).add(Arrays.asList(Arrays.copy(k,1,k.length));
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong in accepting this as answer but k[1] doesn't really works.. when you have a string like folder1/A/B, k[1] only accounts /A and omits B..

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Map<String, List<String>>` to do that.

1. First read the file line by line (using `BufferedReader` or equivalent)
2. Split the string using `"/"` and get the **main folder** (in your case `folder1, folder2`)
3. Add the **main folder** as **key** to the `map`, and if the key exists get the value which is `List<String>` and add the path (which is `B/H, A` etc)

EDIT: Complete listing

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class ParseFolders {

    public static Map<String, List<String>> parse(List<String> input) {
        Map<String, List<String>> res = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        for(String s : input) {
            String [] arr = s.split("/");
            String key = arr[0];
            String val = s.substring(s.indexOf("/"));
            if(res.containsKey(key)) {
                res.get(key).add(val);
            }
            else {
                List<String> folders = new ArrayList<String>();
                folders.add(val);
                res.put(key, folders);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
        input.add("folder1/A");
        input.add("folder1/B/H");
        input.add("folder1/C/F");
        input.add("folder2/D");
        input.add("folder2/E");
        input.add("folder2/F");
        input.add("folder3/G");
        input.add("folder3/H");
        input.add("folder3/I");

        System.out.println(parse(input));
    }

}
```

And the output

```
{folder1=[/A, /B/H, /C/F], folder3=[/G, /H, /I], folder2=[/D, /E, /F]}
```